# Error establishing a database connection on wordpress sometimes

Tags: database, wordpress

i have a blog with wordpress but sometimes i have problem with that

i got blow error

« Error establishing a database connection This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at %s. This could mean your host's database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password? Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname? Are you sure that the database server is running? If you're unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums »

by searching the internet some say that it can come from the database connection information but my concern in my case is that it only happens occasionally and if I wait 5 minutes and I refresh again, the site works again  correctly, then if I wait a few hours and I try to reconnect the problem comes back again… it happens in my back end and my front end, I have searched in vain I can't find anything in my case please  please help friends, here is the URL of the site:

(https://www.creationsjennah.fr/) host is 1&1 IONOS : offer web hosting option in business plan

I would like to remind you that I am probably the only one to use the site, it is in the test phase in an online environment, I see it in the statistics of my site.

Comment: Seems fine to me right now. Check with IONOS if it keeps happening. Clear the cache in your browser.

Comment: hello, yes it works but at times I have the site which is very very slow at the first start of the site, I do not know where it comes from, from the beginning I have this, I am a WordPress novice so I  I don't know where to turn anymore… I might see with ionos if there's not something wrong with them

Comment: please I really need help I'm lost, ionos told me I need to increase my performance level, I'm currently at level 3: MAX RAM: 9 GB

PROCESS: 900/min

MEMORY LIMIT 640MB

But I don't know if it really comes from that... What do you think ?

THANKS

Comment: It's hard to say I don't know your current setup. My suggestion is that you should disable all plugins that are not absolutely necessary for your site to be viewable,  then check to see if it's still happening. If it's not, then enable plugins one by one to see which one is the offending beast.